# How to select a checkbox based on text match?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

After clicking on button a list of checkbox appears. I want to select a checkbox with input taken from excel sheet.

1.This the button, on click list of checkboxes appears.

[image]

2.The list of checkboxes.

[image]

DOM image:

[image]

Comment: have you done anything yourself?

Answer (score 2):

I would provide the process to solve the problem:

1. First find the element with the text (to be searched) on the web page. (in your case its an `<a>` tag).

My personal suggestion is to use xpath: `//a[contains(text(),'<your text from excel>')]`

2. Then try to find its sibling `input` tag with `type='checkbox'` (either by using `following-sibling or preceding-sibling` on that `<a>` tag.

`//a[contains(text(),'<your text from excel>')]/following-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']`

or

`//a[contains(text(),'<your text from excel>')]/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']`